# Angular - animate time as variable

Tags: angular

I'm writing a lathe simulator in Angular 4. Is it possible to set animate time to a variable?

I've got this component code:

```
@Component({
selector: 'lathe-cell',
templateUrl: './lathe-cell.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./lathe-cell.component.css'],
animations: [
    trigger('latheMould', [
        state('in', style({opacity: 0})),
        state('cuttingStart', style({})),
        state('cuttingEnd', style({ backgroundColor: 'green'})),
        state('out', style({opacity: 0})),
        transition('in => cuttingStart', [
            animate(3000, keyframes([
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(-90px, 43px)', offset: 0 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(-90px, 0px)', offset: 0.4 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)', offset: 1 })
            ]))
        ]),
        transition('cuttingStart => cuttingEnd', [
            animate(5000)
        ]),
        transition('cuttingEnd => out', [
            animate(3600, keyframes([
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(90px, 0px)', offset: 0.5 }),
                style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translate(90px, 80px)', offset: 1 })
            ]))
        ])
    ])
]
})

export class LatheCellComponent implements OnInit {

lathe: Lathe;
state: string = 'in';
logWell: string[] = new Array;

constructor(
    private latheService: LatheService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.latheService.getLathe(+params['id']))
        .subscribe(lathe => this.lathe = lathe);
}
}
```

In a transition `cuttingStart => cuttingEnd` I would like to set the time to a variable `lathe.cuttingTime`. Is this possible?

Some code was omitted for clarity.

Comment: It is not possible yet. You will need to find any other way like obervers

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. However, you can work with animation-callbacks to inform your main lathe logic when an animation has finished (or started, though this is analogue to the time of setting state to the animation triggering value):

```
<div [@latheMould]="state"
     (@latheMould.start)="onStart($event)"
     (@latheMould.done)="onDone($event)">
```